# Java 8 installed but only Java 6 works

Tags: java, java-8

I've downloaded JDK 8 x86 and installed it on Windows 7 x64.

I set the PATH environment variable to the location of Java 8 bin directory.

Now on command prompt `javac` command works but when I wanted to run the compiled class file using java command it got me an `exception` error meaning that the compiler and the java command are not of the same version.

I changed the `PATH` variable so that it pointed to the location of `Java 6` bin directory, recompiled the file and it ran fine using java command.

It's my first time installing `JDK` and I'm a newbie. I would appreciate it if anyone could help me get `JDK` `8` running. If not am I missing something using `JDK 6` instead of `JDK 8?`

Comment: Point JAVA_HOME to the location of Java 8

Comment: Then add %JAVA_HOME%\bin to your PATH

Comment: Make sure that in the `Path` variable, the location for Java is before `%SystemRoot%\system32`. The latter contains a `java.exe` that will be used from the command line if it's the first found on `Path`

Comment: I did all these but still the Java -version shows 1.6.0_19-b04 and I still have the same problem.

Comment: Try executing `where java` on the command line to see where `java` is being executed from

Comment: Are you sure the program (cmd?) has read the new values? In the case of cmd you must open a new window. A reboot makes everything reload it of course.

Comment: Post details of your path settings, that may help us in resolving the issue.

Comment: How about de-installing that outdated JDK6?

Comment: Thanks Holger. I uninstalled Java 6 and now the problem is solved. I hope java 8 works fine with my already installed programs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the default Java used by your system. You can achieve this by changing the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. It should point to the desired Java installation.

If you don't know how to change the system variables just google it, there are a lot of tutorials on how to do it. For Unix systems make sure you search for a persistent change.